# Kotlin lazy block not executed when using Mockito and InjectMocks

Tags: mockito, kotlin

I'm using Mockito to test my Kotlin code.  It's a web app and I use spring to inject values into some fields.

For example, my class snippet looks something like this:

```
class MyComponent {

    @Inject private lateinit var request: HttpServletRequest
    @Inject private lateinit var database: Database
```

To mimic this in my unit test I use the `@Mock` and `@InjectMocks` annotations from Mockito.  So my test looks something like this:

```
class MyComponentTest {

    @Mock private lateinit var request: HttpServletRequest
    @Mock private lateinit var database: Database

    @InjectMocks private lateinit var sut: MyComponent

    @Before
    fun setup() {
       MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)
    }
```

Which all works fine.  However, I also have a lazy initialization block in my component like this:

```
val user: User by lazy {
    database.findUser()
}

fun getUsername(): String {
    return user.name
}
```

When my test calls `myComponent.getUsername()` I would expect `database.findUser()` to be called as it initializes `user` but this doesn't happen.

If I put a breakpoint in the lazy block, it's never hit.  Now I am assuming this is something to do with the way Mockito and `@InjectMocks` must 'touch' `user` but I don't really know.  If I construct `MyComponent` manually then the lazy block is executed - but this won't inject my mocks.

How can I ensure the lazy block is called correctly from my test?

**UPDATE**:  After a week absence, attempting to reproduce this without any changes and I could not.  Can't explain it.

Comment: It would help if you could provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). As it is right now I cannot copy your code and reproduce the issue you are seeing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've tried to reproduce your problem and was not able to do so. This [gist](https://gist.github.com/miensol/0e14b9e0bf3caf84223b750f23e84b74) provides a working example.

However I would recommend revisiting the way you write tests. Consider following example:

```
class MyComponentTest {

    val request = mock<HttpServletRequest>()
    val database = mock<Database>()
    val sut = MyComponent(request, database)

    @Test
    fun username() {
        Mockito.`when`(database.findUser()).thenReturn(User("test"))

        val username = sut.getUsername()

        MatcherAssert.assertThat(username, Matchers.equalTo("test"))
    }
}
```

Which in my opinion is easier to understand than the one in mentioned [the gist](https://gist.github.com/miensol/0e14b9e0bf3caf84223b750f23e84b74).

In case you're interested the `mock` helper function is a one liner:

```
inline fun <reified T : Any> mock() = Mockito.mock(T::class.java)
```

A full updated example can be found in this [gist](https://gist.github.com/miensol/123ade8ba6a4af307cf628a88606c753).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion to use constructor injection, I like this as it means I can get rid of my lateinits and use vals instead of vars.  As for the original problem I'll update my question with a MCVE, weird though as your gist is pretty much exactly it.

Comment: OK, I came back to this after a week holiday and tried to reproduce my problem without luck.  Something very weird was happening, but my original code with no changes now works.  Thanks for you efforts!

Comment: I want to mention that the gist mentioned in the answer has already been changed to lateinits annotation style which, in my opinion, is more clear.